# How to display image while minimizing window size to mobile view

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to display icon image while minimizing window. An image is displaying while resizing screen size. But If i minimizing it and refresh the page, image is collapsing with desktop view menu...It is working only for resizing. In tab or mobile view if we refresh it, it is collpasing with desktop view menu...I tried with media query too.but no result. Anyone guide me pls?

```
 <img src="myPicture.png" id="imgid">

    media only screen and (max-width : 320px)
    {
        #imgid
        {
            display:inline-block;
            position:absolute;
        }
//This is desktop view list item which needs to be hide under mypicture.
        #ullist
       {
          display:none;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
     
    #imgid
    {
           display: block;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 420px) {
     
    #imgid
    {
           display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="myPicture.png" id="imgid" width="100" height="100" >
```

Answer (score 0):

By placing the script before the body tag, it resolves the problem.